# How to convert an OpportunityChangeEvent to an Opportunity object?

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, sobject

I am writing an async apex trigger for Opportunity.

The trigger gives me an OpportunityChangeEvent object which has all the fields of Opportunity (in addition to fields like "ChangeEventHeader")

Now my downstream service method expects a "SObject" in its parameter.
How do I convert my changeEvent object to a sObject?

I tried converting the event to a map and populating the values to a new Opportunity

```
    OpportunityChangeEvent event = Trigger.New.get(0);
    Map<String, Object> eventMap = event.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
    eventBus.changeEventHeader changeEventHeader = event.ChangeEventHeader;
    String recordId = changeEventHeader.recordIds.get(0);

    SObject newObj = Opportunity.sObjectType.newSObject();
    for(String changedField: changeEventHeader.changedFields) {
        newObj.put(changedField, eventMap.get(changedField));
    }
```

The problem with this approach is I am not able to set read-only fields like `LastModifiedDate`
I get the error `Field LastModifiedDate is not editable`}

Another I tried was to convert the map to json and deserialize it to Opportunity

```
Map<String, Object> sObjectMap = new Map<String, Object>();
for(String changedField: changeEventHeader.changedFields) {
   sObjectMap.put(changedField, eventMap.get(changedField));
}
String sObjectMapJson = Json.serialize(sObjectMap);
SObject newObj = (Opportunity)JSON.deserialize(sObjectMapJson, Opportunity.class);
```

This works, but seems like a very convoluted way of achieving this.

Is there a native way (or atleast a more straightforward way) of getting an Opportunity object from a Change Event object?

Comment: If you absolutely need all the fields, including read-only fields, formulas, etc, JSON is the way to go.